# Simple HTML table td spacing - Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

So I'm using Rails to put data into a table

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>[Rails Content]</td>
        <td>[Rails Content]</td>
        <td>[Rails Content]</td>
        <td>[Rails Content]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>[Rails Content]</td>
        <td>[Rails Content]</td>
        <td>[Rails Content]</td>
        <td>[Rails Content]</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

---

The problem is, I have another table where it will only be displaying one entry. I want it to take up **the same** space as before (25% of the whole row) as if there were more entries going to follow it. The current result of this is an awkward 100% width `<td>`.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>[Rails Content]</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Any help is super appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is it gonna be populated through AJAX or normal Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this was simply put 3 extra `<td></td>`. If anyone else has other better ways to do this, maybe with CSS, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

This would be a problem if the code is gonna be populated through AJAX. But as I can see, there's no JavaScript here, I assume that it would be just Ruby on Rails. So in that case, have conditions like:

```
<% if only one image %>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>[Rails Content]</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<% else if only two images %>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>[Rails Content]</td>
        <td>[Rails Content]</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```